# calculate the number of topics for each student that belong to all cluster in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I have two dataframes (df1, df2), df1 contains the student name, topic preference of each student and df2 contains each topic in df1 with its cluster or group.

Here is a sample input dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'martin', 'jack'],
        'topics':['algebra; atom; evolution', 'chemical reaction; calculus; quantum',
                  'geometry; botany; electricity; mechanics',
                  'zoology; number theory; atom; evolution; calculus']})
```

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'topics':['algebra', 'calculus', 'geometry','number theory', 'atom', 'chemical reaction',
                              'evolution', 'botany', 'zoology', 'electricity', 'quantum', 'mechanics'],    
                    'cluster':[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
                   })
```

[image]

How could I calculate the number of topics for each student that belong to all cluster?

for example, for the first student (Tom):

```
for cluster 0, the number of topics=1 
for cluster 1, the number of topics=1
for cluster 2, the number of topics=1
for cluster 3, the number of topics=0
```

and calculate the total number of topics for each student?

for example:-

```
For Tom, the total number of topics= 3
For Martin, the total number of topics= 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
df = (
    df1.assign(topics=df1.topics.str.split(r";\s*"))
       .explode("topics")
       .merge(df2, on="topics", how="left")
       .pivot_table(
            index="Name", columns="cluster", aggfunc="count",
            fill_value=0, margins=True
        )
       .droplevel(0, axis=1)
)
```

Result (`df`):

```
cluster  0  1  2  3  All
Name                    
Tom      1  1  1  0    3
jack     2  1  2  0    5
martin   1  0  1  2    4
nick     1  1  0  1    3
All      5  3  4  3   15
```

---

Regarding the question in the comment: You could do something like

```
ser = df.iloc[:, :-1].div(df.All, axis=0).apply(list, axis=1)
```

with the result

```
Name
Tom       [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.333...
jack                                   [0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.0]
martin                               [0.25, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5]
nick      [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.0, ...
All       [0.3333333333333333, 0.2, 0.26666666666666666,...
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks, could I create a new column that saves vector values for each student, for example for Tom (v=1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0/3) and for jack (v=2/5, 1/5, 2/5, 0/5) and etc.

Comment: @AlexAM I'm not sure I understand correctly. See my edit, maybe that's what you're looking for?